# Glassfish server wont start after I close Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, glassfish-3

Basically I can start glassfish after installing. But after I exit Netbeans I can´t run it even from console. I am using Netbeans 7.1.2 and glassfish 3.1.2.
This is my output from console. My secret guess is that it will be problem in file path but I still hope that not. Could someone help? Hope that this is not some repost, if so pls atttach link to solution, I couldnt find anything. Thanks a lot

```
C:\Moje programy\glassfishServer\bin>asadmin start-domain personal_domain_2
Waiting for personal_domain_2 to start ...Error starting domain personal_domain_2.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
ERROR: Error parsing system bundle export statement: org.osgi.framework; version=1.6.0, org.osgi.framework.launch; version=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework.wiring; version=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework.startlevel; version=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle; version=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework.hooks.resolver; version=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework.hooks.service; version=1.1.0, org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving; version=1.0.0, org.osgi.service.packageadmin; version=1.2.0, org.osgi.service.startlevel; version=1.1.0, org.osgi.service.url;
ERROR: Bundle jaxb-api [2] Error starting file:/C:/Moje%20programy/glassfishServer/glassfish/modules/endorsed/jaxb-api-osgi.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle jaxb-api [2]: Unable to resolve 2.0: missing requirement [2.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.activation))
ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.metro.webservices-api-osgi [3] Error starting file:/C:/Moje%20programy/glassfishServer/glassfish/modules/endorsed/webservices-api-osgi.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.glassfish.metro.webservices-api-osgi [3]: Unable to resolve 3.0: missing requirement [3.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.bind)(version>=2.2.0)) [caused by: Unable to resolve 2.0: missing requirement [2.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.activati
ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.main.core.glassfish [101] Error starting file:/C:/Moje%20programy/glassfishServer/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle org.glassfish.main.core.glassfish [101].)
ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-adapter [203] Error starting file:/C:/Moje%20programy/glassfishServer/glassfish/modules/osgi-adapter.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-adapter [203]: Unable to resolve 203.0: missing requirement [203.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.enterprise.module)(version>=1.1.0)) [caused by: Unable to resolve 121.0: missing requirement [121.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.jvnet.hk2.config)(vers
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be zero length.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.normalizeExportClauses(ManifestParser.java:729)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.<init>(ManifestParser.java:191)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.<init>(ExtensionManager.java:220)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.<init>(Felix.java:374)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkFactory.newFramework(FrameworkFactory.java:28)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher.launchOSGiFrameWork(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:77)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:128)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
feb 17, 2015 8:14:04 PM BundleProvisioner install
WARNING: Failed to install file:/C:/Moje%20programy/glassfishServer/glassfish/modules/flashlight-extra-jdk-packages.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not create bundle object.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2785)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install(BundleProvisioner.java:446)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.installBundles(BundleProvisioner.java:208)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.addExtensionBundle(ExtensionManager.java:401)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2751)
        ... 13 more

feb 17, 2015 8:14:04 PM BundleProvisioner install
WARNING: Failed to install file:/C:/Moje%20programy/glassfishServer/glassfish/modules/glassfish-corba-omgapi.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not create bundle object.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2785)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install(BundleProvisioner.java:446)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.installBundles(BundleProvisioner.java:208)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.addExtensionBundle(ExtensionManager.java:401)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2751)
        ... 13 more

feb 17, 2015 8:14:04 PM BundleProvisioner install
WARNING: Failed to install file:/C:/Moje%20programy/glassfishServer/glassfish/modules/glassfish-extra-jre-packages.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not create bundle object.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2785)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install(BundleProvisioner.java:446)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.installBundles(BundleProvisioner.java:208)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.addExtensionBundle(ExtensionManager.java:401)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2751)
        ... 13 more

feb 17, 2015 8:14:04 PM BundleProvisioner install
WARNING: Failed to install file:/C:/Moje%20programy/glassfishServer/glassfish/modules/glassfish-oracle-jdbc-driver-packages.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not create bundle object.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2785)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install(BundleProvisioner.java:446)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.installBundles(BundleProvisioner.java:208)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.addExtensionBundle(ExtensionManager.java:401)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2751)
        ... 13 more

feb 17, 2015 8:14:04 PM BundleProvisioner install
WARNING: Failed to install file:/C:/Moje%20programy/glassfishServer/glassfish/modules/javax.transaction.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not create bundle object.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2785)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install(BundleProvisioner.java:446)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.installBundles(BundleProvisioner.java:208)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.addExtensionBundle(ExtensionManager.java:401)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2751)
        ... 13 more

feb 17, 2015 8:14:04 PM BundleProvisioner install
WARNING: Failed to install file:/C:/Moje%20programy/glassfishServer/glassfish/modules/webservices-extra-jdk-packages.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not create bundle object.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2785)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install(BundleProvisioner.java:446)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.installBundles(BundleProvisioner.java:208)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.addExtensionBundle(ExtensionManager.java:401)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2751)
        ... 13 more

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle jaxb-api [2]: Unable to resolve 2.0: missing requirement [2.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.activation)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3826)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1868)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:295)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.glassfish.metro.webservices-api-osgi [3]: Unable to resolve 3.0: missing requirement [3.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.bind)(version>=2.2.0)) [caused by: Unable to resolve 2.0: missing requirement [2.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.activation)]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3826)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1868)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:295)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2128)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1432)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:72)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.getClassByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1317)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.createBundleActivator(Felix.java:4170)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1972)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1895)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:295)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator not found by org.glassfish.main.core.glassfish [101]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1460)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:72)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 14 more
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-adapter [203]: Unable to resolve 203.0: missing requirement [203.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.enterprise.module)(version>=1.1.0)) [caused by: Unable to resolve 121.0: missing requirement [121.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.jvnet.hk2.config)(version>=1.1.0)) [caused by: Unable to resolve 37.0: missing requirement [37.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.management)]]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3826)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1868)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:295)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException: No GlassFishRuntime available
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:164)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:112)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException: No GlassFishRuntime available
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.getGlassFishRuntime(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:202)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:162)
        ... 9 more
Error stopping framework: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher$1.run(GlassFishMain.java:203)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=64m; support was removed in 8.0

Command start-domain failed.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so I forgot to check Java version. Uninstalled java8 and tadaaa it is working. hope that it will help someone